# Make multiple datasets in one list

Tags: r, dataset

I have a simulation study, where 1000 datasets are generated.

For example,

```
A<-1:50
B<-1:60
C<-1:36
...

Set1<-data.frame(A,runif(50))
Set2<-data.frame(B,runif(60))
Set3<-data.frame(C,runif(36))
...
Set1000<-data.frame(C,runif(56))
Etc.
```

I am wondering how these generated datasets are placed in one list, and then I can use lapply, sapply to cycle through them.

Peter Langfelder gave an example for three datasets here, https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-November/294542.html

How about 1000 datasets?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `get()`, e.g. `mget(paste0("Set", 1:3))`?

Comment: i'm glad; i'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get` and `mget` can be used to retrieve elements of the workspace (or another environment),

```
datasets <- mget(paste0("Set", 1:3))
```

will return a list containing your first 3 datasets.